# Bash: if statement always succeeding

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement

I have the following if statement to check if a service, newrelic-daemon in this case, is running...

```
if [ $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep newrelic-daemon | wc -l) > 0 ]; then
    echo "New Relic is already running."
```

The problem is it's always returning as true, i.e. "New Relic is already running". Even though when I run the if condition separately...

```
ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep newrelic-daemon | wc -l
```

... it returns 0. I expect it to do nothing here as the value returned is =0 but my IF condition says >0.

Am I overlooking something here?

Comment: `> 0` is writing a file named 0, not running a numeric comparison.

Comment: BTW, in general, grepping the process table is a code smell (an indication that you're doing something you probably shouldn't, ie. less robust than a best-practices approach). If you're doing process supervision correctly, you can just ask your operating system which services are running -- if it's systemd-based, then `if systemctl is-active newrelic-daemon`; for runit, `sv status newrelic-daemon`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to do a numeric comparison in `[`...`]` with `>`. That doesn't work; to compare values as numbers, use `-gt` instead:

```
if [ "$(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -c newrelic-daemon)" -gt 0 ]; then
```

The quotation marks around the command expansion prevent a syntax error if something goes horribly wrong (e.g. `$PATH` set wrong and the shell can't find `grep`). Since you tagged this `bash` specifically, you could also just use `[[`...`]]` instead of `[`...`]` and do without the quotes.

As another Bash-specific option, you could use `((`...`))` instead of either form of square brackets. This version is more likely to generate a syntax error if anything goes wrong (as the arithmetic expression syntax *really* wants all arguments to be numbers), but it lets you use the more natural comparison operators:

```
if (( "$(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -c newrelic-daemon)" > 0 )); then
```

In both cases I used `grep -c` instead of `grep | wc -l`; that way I avoided an extra process and a bunch of interprocess I/O just so `wc` can count lines that `grep` is already enumerating.

But since you're just checking to see if there are any matches at all, you don't need to do either of those; the last `grep` will exit with a true status if it finds anything and false if it doesn't, so you can just do this:

```
if ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -q newrelic-daemon; then
```

(The `-q` keeps `grep` from actually printing out the matching lines.)

Also, if the process name you're looking for is a literal string instead of a variable, my favorite trick for this task is to modify that string like this, instead of piping through an extra `grep -v grep`:

```
if ps -ef | grep -q 'newrelic[-]daemon'; then
```

You can pick any character to put the square brackets around; the point is to create a regular expression pattern that matches the target process name but *doesn't* match the pattern itself, so the `grep` process doesn't find its own `ps` line.

Finally, since you tagged this `linux`, note that most Linux distros ship with a combination `ps` + `grep` command called `pgrep`, which does this for you without your having to build a pipeline:

```
if pgrep newrelic-daemon >/dev/null; then
```

(The MacOS/BSD version of `pgrep` accepts a `-q` option like `grep`, which would let you do without the `>/dev/null` redirect, but the versions I've found on Linux systems don't seem to have that option.)

There's also `pidof`; I haven't yet encountered a system that had `pidof` without `pgrep`, but should you come across one, you can use it the same way:

```
if pidof newrelic-daemon >/dev/null; then
```

Comment: Should probably quote the expansions. Granted, a pipeline in `grep -c` *should* always emit a single integer on stdout, but if somehow it didn't (bad `PATH`?), you don't want `[ -gt 0]` being run, when `[ "" -gt 0 ]` would provide a more useful error message.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have given you more details. I would do what you are trying to do with:

```
if pidof newrelic-daemon >/dev/null; then
  echo "New Relic is already running."
fi
```

or even

```
pidof newrelic-daemon >/dev/null && echo "New Relic is already running."
```

Comment: If one doesn't have `pidof`, it's also worth looking for `pgrep`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare integers with `test` you have to use the `-gt` option. See:

```
man test
```

or

```
man [
```

Answer (score 1):

@Stephen: Try(change `[` to `[[` into your code along with fi which will complete the if block completely):

```
if [[ $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep newrelic-daemon | wc -l) > 0 ]]; then
    echo "New Relic is already running."
fi
```

Comment: Technically this works, but I wouldn't call it good practice -- it's running a string comparison, not a numeric comparison. That's fine for comparing against `0`, but if you were running `[[ 5 > 10 ]]`, the results would be surprising.